# Ubuntu Boot Logo low resolution

Tags: boot, grub2, logo

I'm curious. After installing Ubuntu, the boot screen is not shown full screen. It's shown in sort of a black frame like the resolution isn't high enough. When I change it to my native monitor resolution 1920x1080 the letters and logo assume the new resolution but the logo still isn't full screen. When I check the resolutions available for GRUB2 with vbeinfo command my resolution isn't listed. But I noticed, when I boot up from the Ubuntu Installation USB the boot logo is shown in full 1920x1080 resolution, no black bars and all. It's not a serious problem but it really annoys me. Can anyone help or suggest why this is happening.

P.S. I'm using proprietary drivers from nvidia-current-updates.

Answer (score 0):

> P.S. I'm using proprietary drivers from nvidia-current-updates.

This is the problem.

Do this:
into **/etc/default/grub** find the line

```
GRUB_GFXMODE=auto
```

and uncomment/change to

```
GRUB_GFXMODE=1920x1080
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep
```

Then, into **/etc/grub.d/00_header** find the line starting with

```
if [ "x${GRUB_GFXMODE}" = "x" ] ...
```

and change it to

```
if [ "x${GRUB_GFXMODE}" = "x" ] ; then GRUB_GFXMODE=1920x1080 ; fi
```

then, below, find the block below

```
set gfxmode=${GRUB_GFXMODE}
```

and change it to

```
set gfxmode=${GRUB_GFXMODE}
set gfxpayload=keep
load_video
insmod gfxterm
```

after, execute

```
sudo update-grub
```

Reboot and all should be OK.

Tested starting from Ubuntu 13.04 and Mint 15 with a Nvidia GeForce 9600 GT.